# EF 5 - The number of primary key values passed must match the number of primary key values defined on the entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I ran into this error message while using EF5. Wondering if anyone has the answer for this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Budget.Data
{

    [Table("BudgetItems")]
   public class BudgetItemRepository
    {
         [Column("MdaCode")]
        public int MDACode { get; set; }
        [Column("PersonalCost")]
        public double PersonnelCost { get; set; }
        [Column("OverheadCost")]
        public double OverheadCost { get; set; }
        [Column("RecurrentCost")]
        public int RecurrentCost { get; set; }
        [Column("CapitalCost")]
        public double Capital { get; set; }

        public double Allocation { get; set; }
        [Column("BudgetYear")]
        public String BudgetYear { get; set; }
         [Column("RecordCreatedDate")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        [Column("RecordLastModifiedDate")]
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<BudgetItemRepository> budgetitems { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<BudgetLineItemRepository> budgetlineitems { get; set; }
         [Column("BudgetItemID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where did you get that error message? You had to call some method to get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't declare a primary key for the entity. You do this by marking the primary key column with the [Key} attribute. Assuming this is the Id property, the code would look like:

```
[Column("BudgetItemID")]
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: In many of the examples online, including Scott Gu's example on Code First, there KeyAttribute is not used. Why did I have to use this attribute in my case?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Whether or not that works depends upon how you configure your DataContext (and I forgot about that convention, sorry). The other possibility is that the actual table has a compound primary key that doesn't match the single Id column.

Comment: @JeffSiver - That is exactly my case. Figuring out how to accommodate this situation right now... any pointers?

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole, I believe putting the Key attribute on each column that participates in the key will work. You can also do it with code configuration: HasKey(k=>k.firstKeyProperty, k.secondKeyProperty);

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole This may be years late, but I encountered the same issue. I resolved it by looking in the `Mapping` folder for my models. In there, the PK was defined as a cluster of properties. Changing it to something like this `HasKey(k=>k.Id)` should've fixed the issue